# Remote Desktop Management software for managing multiple Windows machines

Tags: windows, remote-access

I am looking for a program that will allow me to view multiple (8+) computers on one main computer. All these computers are monitoring data, and many are in different locations (same network).

The program needs to allow the computer that is being enslaved to still have simultaneous control (so if I'm in front of the enslaved computer, I don't have to run all the way back to the master). Also, if possible, the program should show the different desktops in tabulated format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the different desktops in tabulated format, you can use [MultiVNC](http://multivnc.sourceforge.net/):

- Free, open-source, cross-platform
- Tabbed VNC viewer:

[image]

- by default with most VNC servers, the computer that is being enslaved still has simultaneous control.
- Note that it doesn't work with RealVNC server when the connection is encrypted.

Comment: For this program to work, do I already have to have a VNC program installed?

Comment: @JohnS Nothing client-side, but a standard VNC server server-side (UltraVNC, RealVNC without encryption, etc.).

Comment: Alright, well the company I work for granted me access rights for RealVNC, but everything is encrypted. Is there any solution that accepts the encrypted version?

Comment: @JohnS I haven't met any but would be interested!

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer Thumbnails over tabs, you can use [VNC Thumbnail Viewer](http://thetechnologyteacher.wordpress.com/vncthumbnailviewer/):

- free
- Windows/OSX/Linux

[image]

Note that it doesn't work with RealVNC server when the connection is encrypted.